# Include layout inside another one: strange behavior of wrap_content

Tags: android, android-layout, layout

I have a layout (principal) that include another layout. In principal Layout I include the other one like

```
<include
    android:id="@+id/other_layout_id"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    layout="@layout/other_latyout_name" />
```

and this is code of my other layout that represent a custom row with some elements (some text and a button):

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/relative_row_opponent"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

<!-- other widget, all with wrap_content -->
```

If inside principal layout, in include tag i specify

```
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
```

other layout take all vertical space inside principal layout and I doesn't expect this behavior. why happen this?

Answer (score 0):

Acoording to the http://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/reusing-layouts.html#Include

> You can also override all the layout parameters (any android:layout_* attributes) of the included layout's root view by specifying them in the `<include/>` tag.

Also

> However, if you want to override layout attributes using the `<include>` tag, you must override both `android:layout_height` and `android:layout_width` in order for other layout attributes to take effect.

So what you should do is

```
<include
    android:id="@+id/other_layout_id"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    layout="@layout/other_layout_name" />
```

Here I have included `android:layout_width` property along with `android:layout_height` as suggested by the website.

I haven't tested it. But hope it helps.